# Should toString() method be used to display object in Grails?

Tags: grails, groovy

I have a simple Address domain object that has the following string fields: line1, line2, city, state, zipCode. I'd like to setup the toString() method to display a formatted string skipping any fields that are null.

For example, an Address that does not have a line2 should be displayed as: , ,  (e.g. "1234 My Street, Albuquerque, NM, 12345" rather than "1234 My Street, null, Albuquerque, NM, 12345").

Is there a slick way to do this in groovy other than the following? Also, since Grails generates code that uses the toString() to represent domain objects on the web pages, should I continue to use toString() for display purposes or should I be making a gsp template or something to display and format domain object info? If toString() is just for getting started and should not be used for display purposes long term, then this issue goes away.

```
public String toString() {
    String str = null
    if (line1) {
        str += line1
    }
    if (line2) {
        if (string.empty == false) {
            str += ", "
        }
        str += line2
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
"${number} ${street} ${extended?:''}, ${city}, ${state}, ${zipcode}".replace(' ,',',')
```

or

```
["$number $street",extended,city,state,zipcode].minus(null).join(', ')
```

Where should you do it is a design decision, is the formatted address gonna be printed in a several different places? If so, you could make a taglib. Generally, I like to keep data formatting responsibilities away from domain classes.